# How to return multiple ResponseEntity including JSONObject in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

How to return multiple ResponseEntity including JSONObject in Spring MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CreateEndPoint is propably a simple java bean class with getters and setters and standard mapper does not have problem with serializing it to JSON. JSONObject is wrapper for map and does not provide simple getters and setters and mapper does not know what to do with that. 
Instead of this:

```
return new ResponseEntity<org.json.JSONObject>(dataFromResponse,
                    HttpStatus.OK);
```

try this:

```
return new ResponseEntity<String>(dataFromResponse.toString(), HttpStatus.OK);
```

You can also try to provide additional a mapper which invokes toString() operation for given types instead of using getters and setters but I think this solution is more simple.

Comment: Yes, I have tried myself same like above but answer was too late :)